# OCaml Array Slice?

Tags: arrays, ocaml, slice, sub-array

I'm learning OCaml, and one thing that I have not been able to discover how to do is taking a slice of an array. For example, if I want to extract the subarray of 3 elements starting from index 2, I have to do: `[|array.(2); array.(3); array.(4)|]`. This gets tedious. Is there any function that can easily and quickly give an array slice? If not, how would I go about rolling my own function for such behaviour?

Really appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Array.sub is easier  to use than blit :

```
let v=[|0;1;2;3;4;5|];;
let v'=Array.sub v 2 3;;
# val v' : int array = [|2; 3; 4|]
```

`Array.sub a` start len returns a fresh array of length len,
containing the elements number **start** to **start + len - 1** of array a.

Answer (score 4):

There is  `Array.blit v1 o1 v2 o2 len` copies len elements from array v1, starting at element number o1, to array v2, starting at element number o2.

You can also use Array.init  int -> (int -> 'a) -> 'a array :

> let b = Array.init 3 (fun x -> array.(x+2));;

Comment: This has also been useful. Thanks so much!